# How to solve list index out of range in list of tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples, slice

I get an error when I try to enter the tuple in the list

```
  sorted_fits = list(sorted_map_fit_ind.keys())

  for i, fit_i in enumerate(sorted_fits):    
    current = fit_i
    currentFront.append(current)  #add to currentFront
    next = sorted_fits[i+1:]

    if (current < next[0:1][0]):
       maxFront +=1
      #  fronts[maxFront].append(current)
      #  current.clear()        

    print("current:", current) 
    print("next:", next[0:1][0])
```

originally, when I only do [0:1], it is completely fine

```
 print("current:", current[1]) 
 print("next:", next[0:1])
```

The output is

```
current: 0.5314628962344409
next: [(0.7302657961063032, 2.4412465716032075)]
current: 2.4412465716032075
next: [(0.8941905416221944, 2.148996667396062)]
current: 2.148996667396062
next: [(1.04917653181772, 3.5408676364120506)]
current: 3.5408676364120506
next: [(1.0828395581966677, 1.2350063877828519)]
current: 1.2350063877828519
next: [(1.2112972183921007, 2.96789545886131)]
current: 2.96789545886131
next: [(1.327964792821476, 3.9343512379175984)]
```

When I do next[0:1][0],

```
print("current:", current[1]) 
print("next:", next[0:1][0])
```

Output

```
current: 0.5314628962344409
next: (0.7302657961063032, 2.4412465716032075)
current: 2.4412465716032075
next: (0.8941905416221944, 2.148996667396062)
current: 2.148996667396062
next: (1.04917653181772, 3.5408676364120506)
current: 3.5408676364120506
next: (1.0828395581966677, 1.2350063877828519)
```

Stack Trace

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-47-c913508b61c0> in <module>()
     50   return maxFront
     51 
---> 52 efficient_NSGAII(pop)

<ipython-input-47-c913508b61c0> in efficient_NSGAII(population)
     39     next = sorted_fits[i+1:]
     40 
---> 41     if (current < next[0:1][0]):
     42        maxFront +=1
     43       #  fronts[maxFront].append(current)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Is there any suggestion where I can enter the tuple without getting this type of errors

Comment: Where did you get that error?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @VIVID when I do next[0:1][0]

Comment: But you show that there is output from `next[0:1][0]` in your second code snippet. So, do you get output, or do you get an error? btw Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @quamrana i do get the result but it keeps showing the index error, should I be worried and please explain why I get this error. I don't know why I have the error

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: @quamrana the error is in the first line already, I have already post the full error in the first hand

Comment: Please update your question with the **full** error traceback. This normally includes a stack trace.

Comment: @quamrana I included the stack trace and i found out both the print is index out of range

Comment: So current[1] is out of range. What does that tell you about current?

Comment: Sorry the previous is the wrong run, and I believe the problem of index out of range is happened in next[0:1][0], where I want to delist and only get the tuple i

Comment: Are you saying that it's going beyond the limit, because next is trying to count past the end of sorted_fits indices?  `for i, fit_i in enumerate( sorted_fits[:-1] ):`